# Getting timezone via IP

Tags: php, json, laravel, timezone

I have a problem when I uploaded my website to our server. I have this PHP script in getting the timezone through that URL.

```
$ipInfo = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json');
$ipInfo = json_decode($ipInfo);
```

My problem is it returns a timezone of America/Chicago. But when I access the URL directly to the address bar it return the correct timezone

[image]

Comment: Is your server in America by any chance...?

Comment: Your server probably isn't using the Asia/Manila timezone, but rather America/Chicago. You need to change that in your server - how to do that varies by server type and configuration.

Comment: @Joel In this case it would mean physically moving the server to the Philippines...

Comment: @deceze Right, didn't realise it was ip-based; should have read more thoroughly.

Comment: @deceze answer is what I needed. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ip-api.com responds with data based on the IP from which the request came. If you're in the Philippines and are accessing the website, you'll see information about *yourself*. If your server is in America and is requesting from the site, it'll see information about *itself*.

If you want your server to retrieve information about the client that's visiting it, you'll have to pass along the visiting client's IP. According to [the documentation](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json), you append it to the URL:

```
file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

Comment: You rock. Thank you!. This is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

`http://ip-api.com/json/` is not working anymore (at least for me)

I ended up using this instead:

```sh
curl -s http://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup | grep -oP '(?<=<TimeZone>)(.*)(?=</TimeZone>)'
```